# fix element to element on background image (responsive)

Tags: jquery, css

I try to fix 2 sliders (owl carousel) onto a specific point on a background-image.

The positioning is not the big problem, this is done by jQuery, as one can see in the code below.

The problem is, that when I change the width of the browser, resize only vertical, or resize only horizontal, it only changes the width OR the height. BUT the background-image changes both due to 
background-size:cover.

Picture:
[image: 1 DIV with slider - 2 part of background image - 3 DIV with slider]

```
1 = DIV with slider
2 = part of background-image
3 = DIV with slider
```

**HTML**
The Code for #1 div:

```
<div id="slider-team" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
 <div class="team-item">
  <div class="team-box">
   <div class="team-photo image-works">
    <img alt="Team" class="img-correction lazy" src="img/team/team-01.png">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

## 2 brown DIV:

```
<div class="slider-team-vis">
 <div class="vis-item">
  <p class="vis-name">Forname<br> Name</p>
  <p class="vis-titel">titel</p>
  <p class="vis-email">info@email.com</p>
  <p class="vis-adress">T.XXX.XX XX XX XX<br> info@email.com <br> www.internet.de</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS
DIV #1

```
#slider-team {
        width:18.1%;
        padding-bottom:25%;
            }
```

The image is calculated by the owl slider, which works fine. The problem here is, the width (and height), which has the problem, like described before.

DIV #2 brown

```
.slider-team-vis {
width: 11% !important;
transform: rotate(-3.5deg);
padding-right: 2%;
position:absolute !important;
}
.vis-name {
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: right;
color: #ccc;
font-size: 3vh;
font-weight: 800;
margin-bottom: 0;
line-height: 2.3vh;
letter-spacing: -1px;
padding-right: 2%;
}
```

titel, email and adress are like .vis-name, only smaller font-size, therefore I don't post them here. Saving some space.

The background-image:

```
#page-team-1 {
        overflow:hidden;
        background-image:url(../img/sections/team5.jpg);
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat:  no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size:  cover;
        background-color: #34393b;
        }
```

So, the mapping works perfect, I don't need to put here the jQuery code. 
I tried to keep the ratio of the divs with padding-bottom in percentage, but due to absolute positioning, this seems not work out like it should.
Using vh or vw didn't get me to the wanted results.

Right now, I am getting a headache from this problem. Maybe someone has another idea, how to solve this dilemma...?

Thanks in advance for any idea....and sorry for the long text...

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the headache you could use an aspirine. Works fine for me.

And for dimensions with fixed ratios, you could use the zero-height-padding approach. I just came up with that name btw, so don't try to google it.

Anyway, it makes use of the fact that a percentage bottom/top padding is relative to the *width* of the element, instead of the height, as you would expect it to be. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/padding-bottom):

> Percentages   refer to the width of the containing block

That means that the resulting height of the element will always be relative to the width of the element. And when you put another element inside that element, and position it absolute, it will overlap the padding area, which otherwise would be empty.

Example:

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 300px 0 100px;
  width: 50%;
}

.sizing-element {
  background: red;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 ratio */
  position: relative; /* important! Otherwise the content-element will not hold to this boundaries */
  width: 100%;
}

.content-element {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sizing-element">
    <div class="content-element">
      <h2>Content here</h2>
      <p>But be advised; the element will not grow/shrink based on the content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this example and resize the browser to see how it works. I guess with a few alterations you can make this work for your specific use-case.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough: The brown div is an absolute positioned div, #2 is NOT a div, it is the object seen on the background-image. Due to the Div #1, which is positioned relative, the second div (the brown one) CANNOT be positioned relative, this messes everything up.
Or am I not seeing your point? I DID say above, that I tried PADDING-BOTTOM with percentage to keep the ratio, which doesn't work (position: absolute).

Comment: Ehrm... for my understanding, the #2 is a background image of the element wrapping the full slide? I guess we're looking at a single slide in your example, right? Is it an option to cut out the image and let it be a background image not for the full page / slide but an element itself? And which ratios are messed up exactly, of the brown div? Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Btw; that it is positioned absolutely doesn't really matter. You can always add another div, and besides that; this technique also works on absolutely positioned divs. And have you tried the aspirin yet?

Comment: Sorry, not clear enough. The background image is covering the whole browser. It is set to background-size: cover;
#1 is only an element in this picture. I left he rest of the things seen on the picture out, because they don't matter.
It works like this: In DIV #1 you see a picture, in the brown div, call it #3, the info about this img are displayed. You click on next, the img changes AND the information in div #3 change too. 
When I change the width of the browser ( NOT the height) the information gets a new width, no new height, BUT the background-image changes both, due to cover

Comment: And no, I didn't try aspirin. I drink more water and went to inhale "fresh" air...
I will try a snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I can't make a snippet. Doesn't work, because I can't put in a background-image, to map the elements onto it...But I changed some info-explanation and a new image, to make all more clear.